# How to override generic function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

Lets consider the code:

```
interface Base{
    
    fun <T:Number> foo(): T
}

class Child: Base {
    override fun foo(): Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

The error is

```
Conflicting overloads...
```

How can I fix it ?

### update

Thanks for sweeper

```
interface Base<T: Number>{

    fun foo(): T
}

class Child: Base<Int> {
    override fun foo(): Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like `foo` should not be generic in the first place. Instead, `Base` should be  `interface Base<T: Number>` and `class Child: Base<Int>`.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, it is working. Is this the only way ?

Comment: The only way to do *what*? You didn't explain what you are trying to do by having generics here. If all you want is to "override `foo`", then just get rid of all the generics.

Comment: @Sweeper I have a base class with generic foo which I can't change and I want to override foo on the child class

Comment: If you can't change the base class, then you cannot override with a function that returns `Int`. The base class requires `foo` to work with *all* `T` that inherits `Number`, while your `Child` can only work with `Int`.